# Environment.GetFolderPath(...CommonApplicationData) is still returning "C:\Documents and Settings\" on Vista

Tags: c#, .net, special-folders

As I understand it, you're supposed to use the `Environment.GetFolderPath` method so you have OS independent code...

Windows XP uses `C:\Documents and Settings\`. Windows Vista uses `C:\ProgramData` and `C:\Users`.

I'm using the code below on a Windows Vista computer and it's returning a `C:\Documents and Settings\` directory instead of `C:\ProgramData` like it should... Any ideas?

```
    string commonAppData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
    try
    {
        File.CreateText(
            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) +
            "\\mycompany\\uid");
        log.Debug("Created file successfully");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error("Unable to create the uid file: ", ex);
    }
```

Comment: Is that Vista installation updated from XP?

Comment: No, It defininetly had Vista when it was brought home from the store...  I guess it's possible that it was "upgraded" by bestbuy or something (seems unlikely).  c:\documents and settings doesn't exist at all if that tells you anything.

Comment: How do you resolve "\\mycompany\\uid" into the path? I want to generate this exact path (with company & ui). Do I have to manually add this data from the assembly?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

My installer copied a log.txt file which had been generated on an XP computer.  I was looking at that log file thinking it was generated on Vista.  Once I fixed my log4net configuration to be "Vista Compatible".  Environment.GetFolderPath was returning the expected results.  Therefore, I'm closing this post.

The following SpecialFolder path reference might be useful:

Output On Windows Server 2003:

```
SpecialFolder.ApplicationData: C:\Documents and Settings\blake\Application Data
SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data
SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles: C:\Program Files
SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFiles: C:\Program Files\Common Files
SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory: C:\Documents and Settings\blake\Desktop
SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData: C:\Documents and Settings\blake\Local Settings\Application Data
SpecialFolder.MyDocuments: C:\Documents and Settings\blake\My Documents
SpecialFolder.System: C:\WINDOWS\system32`
```

Output on Vista:

```
SpecialFolder.ApplicationData: C:\Users\blake\AppData\Roaming
SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData: C:\ProgramData
SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles: C:\Program Files
SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFiles: C:\Program Files\Common Files
SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory: C:\Users\blake\Desktop
SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData: C:\Users\blake\AppData\Local
SpecialFolder.MyDocuments: C:\Users\blake\Documents
SpecialFolder.System: C:\Windows\system32
```

Comment: Why would a log4net configuration have anything to do with Environment.GetFolderPath? As for "Any ideas?", yes, you get the first result as an ordinary user, and the second result running as Admin, e.g. when running an elevated installer or a service.

Comment: Also, I think newbies reading all these listings should be aware that these are not necessarily fixed paths on an OS, but can be pretty much anything on "your" machine. Never hardcode - instead use GetFolderPath, or you'll be sorry one day. Oh, and do use Path.Combine rather than the plus operator.

Comment: on wondows10, `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` for some reason returns `CommonApplicationData`. and hence is creating the folders in the app path itself

Comment: @mrid `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` is an enum; you need to call `Environment.GetFolderPath()` to return the path, e.g. `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)`.

Answer (score 41):

**Output on  Ubuntu 9.10 -> Ubuntu 12.04 with mono 2.10.8.1:**

```
SpecialFolder.ApplicationData: /home/$USER/.config
SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData: /usr/share
SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles: 
SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory: /home/$USER/Desktop
SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData: /home/$USER/.local/share
SpecialFolder.MyDocuments: /home/$USER
SpecialFolder.System: 

SpecialFolder.Personal: /home/$USER
```

**Output on Ubuntu 16.04 with mono 4.2.1**

```
SpecialFolder.ApplicationData: /home/$USER/.config
SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData: /usr/share
SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles:
SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory: /home/$USER/Desktop
SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData: /home/$USER/.local/share
SpecialFolder.MyDocuments: /home/$USER
SpecialFolder.Desktop: /home/$USER/Desktop
SpecialFolder.Personal: /home/$USER

SpecialFolder.System: 
SpecialFolder.Programs: 
SpecialFolder.Favorites: 
SpecialFolder.Startup: 
SpecialFolder.Recent: 
SpecialFolder.SendTo: 
SpecialFolder.StartMenu: 
SpecialFolder.MyMusic: /home/$USER/Music
SpecialFolder.MyVideos: /home/$USER/Videos
SpecialFolder.MyComputer: 
SpecialFolder.NetworkShortcuts: 
SpecialFolder.Fonts: /home/$USER/.fonts
SpecialFolder.Templates: /home/$USER/Templates
SpecialFolder.CommonStartMenu: 
SpecialFolder.CommonPrograms: 
SpecialFolder.CommonStartup: 
SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory: 
SpecialFolder.PrinterShortcuts: 
SpecialFolder.InternetCache: 
SpecialFolder.Cookies: 
SpecialFolder.History: 
SpecialFolder.Windows: 
SpecialFolder.MyPictures: /home/$USER/Pictures
SpecialFolder.UserProfile: /home/$USER
SpecialFolder.SystemX86: 
SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86: 
SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFiles: 
SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFilesX86: 
SpecialFolder.CommonTemplates: /usr/share/templates
SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments: 
SpecialFolder.CommonAdminTools: 
SpecialFolder.AdminTools: 
SpecialFolder.CommonMusic: 
SpecialFolder.CommonPictures: 
SpecialFolder.CommonVideos: 
SpecialFolder.Resources: 
SpecialFolder.LocalizedResources: 
SpecialFolder.CommonOemLinks: 
SpecialFolder.CDBurning:
```

where $USER is the current user

**Output on Ubuntu 16.04 using dotnet core (3.0.100)**

```
ApplicationData: /home/$USER/.config
CommonApplicationData: /usr/share
ProgramFiles: 
DesktopDirectory: /home/$USER/Desktop
LocalApplicationData: /home/$USER/.local/share
MyDocuments: /home/$USER
System: 
Personal: /home/$USER
```

**Output on Android 6 using Xamarin 7.2**

```
Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData: /data/user/0/$APPNAME/files/.config
Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData: /usr/share
Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles: 
Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory: /data/user/0/$APPNAME/files/Desktop
Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData: /data/user/0/$APPNAME/files/.local/share
Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments: /data/user/0/$APPNAME/files
Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop: /data/user/0/$APPNAME/files/Desktop
Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal: /data/user/0/$APPNAME/files

Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup: 
Environment.SpecialFolder.Recent: 
Environment.SpecialFolder.SendTo: 
Environment.SpecialFolder.StartMenu: 
Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic: /data/user/0/$APPNAME/files/Music
Environment.SpecialFolder.MyVideos: /data/user/0/$APPNAME/files/Videos
Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer: 
Environment.SpecialFolder.NetworkShortcuts: 
Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts: /data/user/0/$APPNAME/files/.fonts
Environment.SpecialFolder.Templates: /data/user/0/$APPNAME/files/Templates
Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonStartMenu: 
Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonPrograms: 
Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonStartup: 
Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory: 
Environment.SpecialFolder.PrinterShortcuts: 
Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache: 
Environment.SpecialFolder.Cookies: 
Environment.SpecialFolder.History: 
Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows: 
Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures: /data/user/0/$APPNAME/files/Pictures
Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile: /data/user/0/$APPNAME/files
Environment.SpecialFolder.SystemX86: 
Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86: 
Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFiles: 
Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFilesX86: 
Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonTemplates: /usr/share/templates
Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments: 
Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonAdminTools: 
Environment.SpecialFolder.AdminTools: 
Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonMusic: 
Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonPictures: 
Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonVideos: 
Environment.SpecialFolder.Resources: 
Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalizedResources: 
Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonOemLinks: 
Environment.SpecialFolder.CDBurning:
```

Where $APPNAME is the name of your Xamarin application (eg. MyApp.Droid)

**Output on Android 11 using MAUI - .net 7.0**

```
Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments: /data/user/0/$APPNAME/files
Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal: /data/user/0/$APPNAME/files
```

**Output on Android 11 using MAUI - .net 8.0**

```
Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments: /data/user/0/$APPNAME/files/Documents
Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal: /data/user/0/$APPNAME/files/Documents
```

**Output on iOS Simulator 10.3 using Xamarin 7.2**

```
ApplicationData: /Users/$USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/$DEVICEGUID/data/Containers/Data/Application/$APPLICATIONGUID/Documents/.config
CommonApplicationData: /usr/share
ProgramFiles: /Applications
DesktopDirectory: /Users/$USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/$DEVICEGUID/data/Containers/Data/Application/$APPLICATIONGUID/Documents/Desktop
LocalApplicationData: /Users/$USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/$DEVICEGUID/data/Containers/Data/Application/$APPLICATIONGUID/Documents
MyDocuments: /Users/$USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/$DEVICEGUID/data/Containers/Data/Application/$APPLICATIONGUID/Documents
Desktop: /Users/$USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/$DEVICEGUID/data/Containers/Data/Application/$APPLICATIONGUID/Documents/Desktop
MyDocuments: /Users/$USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/$DEVICEGUID/data/Containers/Data/Application/$APPLICATIONGUID/Documents
Startup: 
Recent: 
SendTo: 
StartMenu: 
MyMusic: /Users/$USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/$DEVICEGUID/data/Containers/Data/Application/$APPLICATIONGUID/Documents/Music
MyVideos: /Users/$USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/$DEVICEGUID/data/Containers/Data/Application/$APPLICATIONGUID/Documents/Videos
MyComputer: 
NetworkShortcuts: 
Fonts: /Users/$USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/$DEVICEGUID/data/Containers/Data/Application/$APPLICATIONGUID/Documents/.fonts
Templates: /Users/$USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/$DEVICEGUID/data/Containers/Data/Application/$APPLICATIONGUID/Documents/Templates
CommonStartMenu: 
CommonPrograms: 
CommonStartup: 
CommonDesktopDirectory: 
PrinterShortcuts: 
InternetCache: /Users/$USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/$DEVICEGUID/data/Containers/Data/Application/$APPLICATIONGUID/Library/Caches
Cookies: 
History: 
Windows: 
MyPictures: /Users/$USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/$DEVICEGUID/data/Containers/Data/Application/$APPLICATIONGUID/Documents/Pictures
UserProfile: /Users/$USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/$DEVICEGUID/data/Containers/Data/Application/$APPLICATIONGUID
SystemX86: 
ProgramFilesX86: 
CommonProgramFiles: 
CommonProgramFilesX86: 
CommonTemplates: /usr/share/templates
CommonDocuments: 
CommonAdminTools: 
AdminTools: 
CommonMusic: 
CommonPictures: 
CommonVideos: 
Resources: /Users/$USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/$DEVICEGUID/data/Containers/Data/Application/$APPLICATIONGUID/Library
LocalizedResources: 
CommonOemLinks: 
CDBurning:
```

Where $DEVICEGUID is the simulator GUID (depending on the selected simulator)

**Output on ipad 10.3 using Xamarin 7.2**

```
SpecialFolder.MyDocuments: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/$APPLICATIONGUID/Documents
```

**Output on ipad 13.3 using Xamarin 16.4**

```
SpecialFolder.MyDocuments: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/$APPLICATIONGUID/Documents
SpecialFolder.UserProfile: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/$APPLICATIONGUID/Documents
```

**Output on windows 10 using .net core 3.1**

```
SpecialFolder.MyDocuments: C:\Users\$USER\Documents
```

**Output on Ubuntu 18.04 using .net core 3.1**

```
SpecialFolder.MyDocuments: /home/$USER
```

**Output on Ubuntu 22.04 using .net core 7.0.112**

```
SpecialFolder.Personal: /home/$USER
SpecialFolder.MyDocuments: /home/$USER
```

**Output on Ubuntu 22.04 using .net core 8.0.100-rc.2.23502.2**

****WARNING BREAKING CHANGE****

```
   SpecialFolder.Personal: /home/$USER/Documents   
   SpecialFolder.MyDocuments: /home/$USER/Documents
```

**Output on MacOS Catalina using .net core 3.1**

```
SpecialFolder.Desktop: /Users/$USER/Desktop
SpecialFolder.Programs: 
SpecialFolder.MyDocuments: /Users/$USER
SpecialFolder.Favorites: /Users/$USER/Library/Favorites
SpecialFolder.Startup: 
SpecialFolder.Recent: 
SpecialFolder.SendTo: 
SpecialFolder.StartMenu: 
SpecialFolder.MyMusic: /Users/$USER/Music
SpecialFolder.MyVideos: 
SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory: /Users/$USER/Desktop
SpecialFolder.MyComputer: 
SpecialFolder.NetworkShortcuts: 
SpecialFolder.Fonts: /Users/$USER/Library/Fonts
SpecialFolder.Templates: 
SpecialFolder.CommonStartMenu: 
SpecialFolder.CommonPrograms: 
SpecialFolder.CommonStartup: 
SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory: 
SpecialFolder.ApplicationData: /Users/$USER/.config
SpecialFolder.PrinterShortcuts: 
SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData: /Users/$USER/.local/share
SpecialFolder.InternetCache: /Users/$USER/Library/Caches
SpecialFolder.Cookies: 
SpecialFolder.History: 
SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData: /usr/share
SpecialFolder.Windows: 
SpecialFolder.System: /System
SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles: /Applications
SpecialFolder.MyPictures: /Users/$USER/Pictures
SpecialFolder.UserProfile: /Users/$USER
SpecialFolder.SystemX86: 
SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86: 
SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFiles: 
SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFilesX86: 
SpecialFolder.CommonTemplates: 
SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments: 
SpecialFolder.CommonAdminTools: 
SpecialFolder.AdminTools: 
SpecialFolder.CommonMusic: 
SpecialFolder.CommonPictures: 
SpecialFolder.CommonVideos: 
SpecialFolder.Resources: 
SpecialFolder.LocalizedResources: 
SpecialFolder.CommonOemLinks: 
SpecialFolder.CDBurning:
```

**Output on Snap Package - Core 18 using .net core 3.1**

```
Desktop: 
Programs: 
MyDocuments: /home/$USER/snap/$APPNAME/x$VERSIONNUMBER
MyDocuments: /home/$USER/snap/$APPNAME/x$VERSIONNUMBER
Favorites: 
Startup: 
Recent: 
SendTo: 
StartMenu: 
MyMusic: 
MyVideos: 
DesktopDirectory: 
MyComputer: 
NetworkShortcuts: 
Fonts: 
Templates: 
CommonStartMenu: 
CommonPrograms: 
CommonStartup: 
CommonDesktopDirectory: 
ApplicationData: /home/$USER/snap/$APPNAME/x$VERSIONNUMBER/.config
PrinterShortcuts: 
LocalApplicationData: 
InternetCache: 
Cookies: 
History: 
CommonApplicationData: /usr/share
Windows: 
System: 
ProgramFiles: 
MyPictures: 
UserProfile: /home/$USER/snap/$APPNAME/x$VERSIONNUMBER
SystemX86: 
ProgramFilesX86: 
CommonProgramFiles: 
CommonProgramFilesX86: 
CommonTemplates: 
CommonDocuments: 
CommonAdminTools: 
AdminTools: 
CommonMusic: 
CommonPictures: 
CommonVideos: 
Resources: 
LocalizedResources: 
CommonOemLinks: 
CDBurning:
```

Note: I found that if a snap environment if `/home/$USER/snap/$APPNAME/x$VERSION/.local/share` exists then `LocalApplicationData` will return that path. However if the path doesn't exist it returns empty string.

Also testing with dotnet 8 on Linux `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)` returns empty string if $HOME/Documents folder doesn't exist.

Answer (score 31):

**Output on Windows 10**

```
Fonts: C:\Windows\Fonts
CommonStartMenu: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
CommonPrograms: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
CommonStartup: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
CommonDesktopDirectory: C:\Users\Public\Desktop
CommonApplicationData: C:\ProgramData
Windows: C:\Windows
System: C:\Windows\system32
ProgramFiles: C:\Program Files (x86)
SystemX86: C:\Windows\SysWOW64
ProgramFilesX86: C:\Program Files (x86)
CommonProgramFiles: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramFilesX86: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonTemplates: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
CommonDocuments: C:\Users\Public\Documents
CommonAdminTools: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
CommonMusic: C:\Users\Public\Music
CommonPictures: C:\Users\Public\Pictures
CommonVideos: C:\Users\Public\Videos
Resources: C:\Windows\resources
LocalizedResources:
CommonOemLinks:
```

**Code Snippet if you want to log your own**

```
foreach(Environment.SpecialFolder f in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Environment.SpecialFolder)))
{
    string commonAppData = Environment.GetFolderPath(f);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", f, commonAppData);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Will these values be valid with Windows 10 S?

Answer (score 12):

**Output on Windows 7 (64-bit)**

```
SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData: C:\ProgramData 
SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory: C:\Users\Public\Desktop
SpecialFolder.CommonStartMenu: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
SpecialFolder.CommonPrograms: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFiles: C:\Program Files\Common Files
SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFilesX86: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
SpecialFolder.CommonStartup: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles: C:\Program Files
SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86: C:\Program Files (x86)
SpecialFolder.System: C:\Windows\system32
SpecialFolder.SystemX86: C:\Windows\SysWOW64
```

**Output on Windows XP**

```
SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data
SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop
SpecialFolder.CommonPrograms: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs
SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFiles: C:\Program Files\Common Files
SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFilesX86:
SpecialFolder.CommonStartMenu: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu
SpecialFolder.CommonStartup: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles: C:\Program Files
SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86:
SpecialFolder.System: C:\WINDOWS\system32
SpecialFolder.SystemX86: C:\WINDOWS\system32
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a listing of macOS but found nothing, maybe this helps someone.

**Output on macOS Catalina (10.15.7) using net5.0**

```
# SpecialFolders (Only with value)
SpecialFolder.ApplicationData: /Users/$USER/.config
SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData: /usr/share
SpecialFolder.Desktop: /Users/$USER/Desktop
SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory: /Users/$USER/Desktop
SpecialFolder.Favorites: /Users/$USER/Library/Favorites
SpecialFolder.Fonts: /Users/$USER/Library/Fonts
SpecialFolder.InternetCache: /Users/$USER/Library/Caches
SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData: /Users/$USER/.local/share
SpecialFolder.MyDocuments: /Users/$USER
SpecialFolder.MyMusic: /Users/$USER/Music
SpecialFolder.MyPictures: /Users/$USER/Pictures
SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles: /Applications
SpecialFolder.System: /System
SpecialFolder.UserProfile: /Users/$USER

# SpecialFolders (All)
SpecialFolder.AdminTools: 
SpecialFolder.ApplicationData: /Users/$USER/.config
SpecialFolder.CDBurning: 
SpecialFolder.CommonAdminTools: 
SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData: /usr/share
SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory: 
SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments: 
SpecialFolder.CommonMusic: 
SpecialFolder.CommonOemLinks: 
SpecialFolder.CommonPictures: 
SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFiles: 
SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFilesX86: 
SpecialFolder.CommonPrograms: 
SpecialFolder.CommonStartMenu: 
SpecialFolder.CommonStartup: 
SpecialFolder.CommonTemplates: 
SpecialFolder.CommonVideos: 
SpecialFolder.Cookies: 
SpecialFolder.Desktop: /Users/$USER/Desktop
SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory: /Users/$USER/Desktop
SpecialFolder.Favorites: /Users/$USER/Library/Favorites
SpecialFolder.Fonts: /Users/$USER/Library/Fonts
SpecialFolder.History: 
SpecialFolder.InternetCache: /Users/$USER/Library/Caches
SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData: /Users/$USER/.local/share
SpecialFolder.LocalizedResources: 
SpecialFolder.MyComputer: 
SpecialFolder.MyDocuments: /Users/$USER
SpecialFolder.MyMusic: /Users/$USER/Music
SpecialFolder.MyPictures: /Users/$USER/Pictures
SpecialFolder.MyVideos: 
SpecialFolder.NetworkShortcuts: 
SpecialFolder.PrinterShortcuts: 
SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles: /Applications
SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86: 
SpecialFolder.Programs: 
SpecialFolder.Recent: 
SpecialFolder.Resources: 
SpecialFolder.SendTo: 
SpecialFolder.StartMenu: 
SpecialFolder.Startup: 
SpecialFolder.System: /System
SpecialFolder.SystemX86: 
SpecialFolder.Templates: 
SpecialFolder.UserProfile: /Users/$USER
SpecialFolder.Windows:
```

I have replaced my username with $USER.

**Code Snippet from [pogosama](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38491499/8552750).**

```
foreach(Environment.SpecialFolder f in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Environment.SpecialFolder)))
{
    string commonAppData = Environment.GetFolderPath(f);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", f, commonAppData);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```